# r datetime conversion from chr using strptime gives NA

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a data frame containing date time information as characters in the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm but I can't get it to convert e.g

```
 $ LaserStart : chr  "07/12/2014 11:21" "13/12/2014 05:37"
```

I am trying to convert them to date time using

```
data.LotCT$Start <- strptime(data.LotCT$LaserStart, "%d/%B/%Y %H:%M")
```

this runs without producing any errors but when I review the dataframe I have only NA

```
$ Start      : POSIXlt, format: NA NA NA ...
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Why `%B`? Why not `%m` as in `strptime("07/12/2014 11:21", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")`?

Comment: I was following some other SO responses in that came up in my search. But you were correct, that was the error. thanks

Comment: No offence, but you should try *first* following documentation, and only then, as a last resort, follow SO responses. The documentation for `?strptime` is particularly very reach.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and no offense taken, I do try to check but didn't in this case.  All I can say is that SO rarely lets me down so habit brings me here first.

Answer (score 1):

```
> x <- "07/12/2014 11:21"
> y <- strptime(x, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
> strftime(y, '%d/%B/%Y %H:%M')
[1] "12/July/2014 11:21"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out

```
data.LotCT$Start <- strptime(data.LotCT$LaserStart, "%d/%B/%Y %H:%M")
```

should be

```
data.LotCT$Start <- strptime(data.LotCT$LaserStart, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

which gives

```
 $ Start      : POSIXlt, format: "2014-12-07 11:21:00" "2014-12-13 05:37:00"
```

sorry for bothering you all :)